# Installing Chrubuntu on Acer Chromebook C710

Tags: google-chrome, acer, chromebook, chrubuntu

Good afternoon...

I've installed Chrubuntu MANY TIMES before and I've never had this problem when installing it other times.

I followed the instructions from [A Blogspot Post](http://chromeos-cr48.blogspot.com/2012/04/chrubuntu-1204-now-with-double-bits.html) and it has never failed me before.

Not when I finish downloading the 52 files and it tells me it will restart its self into Chrubuntu... It doesn't. It stays off and I am to turn it on either by power button or closing and lifting the lid and it loads into Chrome OS.

Also, when I try to add the "sudo cgpt add -i 6 -P 5 -S 1 /dev/sda" and I restart it doesn't load Chrubuntu and go back to Chrome.

Help?